# Unity3D - Generate a position within a circular band around the player

Tags: unity, geometry

Given a certain condition in my game I need to generate a position around the player.  It needs to be at least 8 meters away from him and within 10 meters, in a circular matter, as in the dotted green area in the picture below.

Can anyone point me into the right direction?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this could work, I haven't tested it, just rotate a normalized vector by a rotation (quaternion) and the vector will rotate; and for the vector to be within your range, just scale it by your minimum range plus the range of space (min + rand(max - min)). You could also try with Quaternion.Euler if Quaternion.Axis does not work:

```
private float minRange = 8.0f;
private float maxRange = 10.0f;

public Vector3 GetPosition()
{
    float randomRotation = Random.Range(0.0f, 360.0f);
    float projection = minRange + Random.Range(minRange, minRange +  (maxRange - minRange));
    // You could also try with Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0)...
    return Quaternion.AngleAxis(randomRotation, Vector3.up) * Vector3.forward * projection;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `Quaternion.AngleAxis(0.0f, randomRotation, 0.0f, Vector3.up)` - does not take 4 arguments.  `Quaternion.AngleAxis(float angle, Vector3 axis)` - Sorry I can't really picture what your code is doing, so I don't really know how to fix it.

Comment: you are right, I fixed it already, what Angle Axis does is that it converts a 3D space rotation into a quaternion (w, x, y, z). By multiplying a quaternion by a vector you rotate a vector (NOTE, that operation is not commutative: q * v != v * q. So make it in that order). By having a normalized vector, if you multiply it you will have a vector of the magnitude of the scalar which will be within your desired range.

Comment: Something is definitely happening, but I think we are not taking in account the position of the dot (player) in the center.    For example, this is dynamic of course, the player is at position (6.0, 0.0, 1.5)

Comment: you are right, at the moment is giving a point relative to the origin. Then just sum that function plus the position of the dot.

Comment: Its working beautifully! I think I understand what's happening. I just get a bit lost in the multiplication of the `Quaternion * Vector3` but I'll look into it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Note that this will have a slightly higher density of samples on the inner edge of the ring than at the outer edge. You can compensate for this if you need strictly uniform distribution, but from radius 8 to 10 the relative difference should not post a major problem for most applications.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get it done:

```
public Vector3 GetPosition2(Vector3 origin, float minRange, float maxRange)
{
    var startingPoint = Random.insideUnitCircle;
    var normalized = startingPoint.normalized;
    var actualPoint = normalized * Random.Range(minRange, maxRange);
    var relativeToOrigin = new Vector3(actualPoint.x, origin.y, actualPoint.y) + origin;

    return relativeToOrigin;
}
```